# Chat Application Can't run on different WIFI connection in java

Tags: java, windows, swing, sockets, client

I developed a **chat application** which is working great on same wifi connections on different machines.

Concept is.. One Server program is running on One machine which is set by ip and particular Port number so that client hit to server on a particular Port number.

There are two wifi connection running FCS and FCS1

My laptop is getting access to FCS wifi and if client interface is running on same wifi it's working; but when it connects to FCS1 the server doesn't get the IP info from the FCS1 network.

I'm not sure whether the problem is redirecting the IP on the router. Do I need to configure the router?

Comment: Welcome to SO.What transport protocol you are using TCP or UDP? How do you know it fails to get ip info? When you say it fails to connect, are you able to ping the destination machine?

Answer (score 0):

If the server and the client are running on two different networks without a valid IP address for the server, you need to use a [VPN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network) connection.

Or if you have control over the router, you could give a static IP address to the server and redirect any traffic on port -say- 7644 on router to server:7644.